# How do I obtain the Sign in with Apple authorization code via Azure B2C?

Tags: access-token, apple-sign-in, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing an Ionic mobile app that uses Sign in with Apple as an Azure B2C identity provider. It returns an access token that contains an idp_access_token. I have read a number of articles on signing in with Apple *without* Azure, and in these articles, Apple returns an id_token and code (authorization code), which I will need to refresh and revoke the token later on to support deleting accounts. Do I need to convert the idp_access_token somehow or does it have to do with the configuration of Azure?

Since I only have an idp_access_token and not an id_token and code, I can't request a validation of the authorization code, refresh the token, nor revoke the token.

I am using the ionic-appauth package to get the token once the user is signed in, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the authorization code.